# Updating data through multiple forms

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a main form with six or seven buttons on it, each button opens a new form which collects information from the user to be stored in separate tables.  So when I input my information into these multiple forms I want it to do one update from the main page on click of the save button.. I tried referencing the table adapter and binding source of each form from the main page but the data gets lost when any of the other forms get hidden.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles savebtn.Click
    Me.Validate()
    ContactBindingSource.EndEdit()
    ContactTableAdapter.Update(CitWeldDataSet.Contact)
    WeldersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    WeldersTableAdapter.Update(CitWeldDataSet.Welders)
    BCP100BindingSource.EndEdit()
    BCP100TableAdapter.Update(CitWeldDataSet.BCP100)
    bcp100.Close()
End Sub
```

How can I store the inputted user data from each form until the user is finally ready to save?

Sorry I am new to vb.net.  I have built my database (access) with relationships to multiple tables but to store these relationships does it all have to be updated in one click or can it be multiple different saves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out what was going on.. There are two binding sources ( one for the query and another for the original tables )

```
Public Sub Changes()

    BCP100BindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    ContactBindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    CSAWQBindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    CWB1BindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    CWB2BindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    JourneymanBindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    PQR1BindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    PQR2BindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    PQR3BindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    WeldersBindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position
    ABindingSource.Position = WeldersBindingSource.Position
    BBindingSource.Position = WeldersBindingSource.Position
    CBindingSource.Position = WeldersBindingSource.Position
    RedsealBindingSource.Position = WeldersBindingSource.Position
    PressureticketBindingSource.Position = WeldersBindingSource.Position
    NotesBindingSource.Position = WelderqueryBindingSource.Position

 End Sub
```

It was calling the Welderquerybindingsource but updating the original table bindingsources.... Might be the long way to do it but it works fine :)
Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Data in the Settings until the User Clicks Save, then you can fill the Tables with the data stored in the Settings.

You can create Settings in: My Project/Settings

Afterwards you can store the Data like this:

```
My.Settings.Form1 = TextBox1.Text
```

And the data in the settings don't get lost when you close a form.

I hope this is what you wanted. :)

Comment: what type of setting would I create? Setting / String / User / Value?

Comment: It depends on what you want to save in the Settings.
For a list you could use the typ StringCollection and i would use User
At the value field you cn set a default value or you left it empty

Comment: Then a StringCollection in the Setting would do it.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can store your data in an object and pass it through as the contstructor for each form:

```
Private TableObject As ObjectType

Public Sub New(tableObject As ObjectType)
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.TableObject = tableObject
    Binding.DataSource = CurrentClient
End Sub
```

The object is effectively passed through to each form as a ByRef and the values from the bound controls will be used when you call the save on the main form.